# how to check if connected to database

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I want to know how to check if my program is connected to database or not.

here is my code::

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    conn.Open()
    If conn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
        MsgBox("YOU ARE CONNECTED TO THE DATABASE")
    Else
        MsgBox("YOU ARE NOT CONNECTED TO THE DATABASE, CONTACT YOUR ADMINISTRATOR")
    End If
    conn.Close()
End Sub
```

this code works fine if the connection string is correct, the message says open; but when the connection is wrong it ends up in error the error is:

```
Login failed for user
```

Here is the Algorithm of what I want to happen:

```
If thisProgram is connected then
 Messagebox ("YOU ARE CONNECTED TO THE DATABASE")
Else
 MessageBox ("YOU ARE NOT CONNECTED TO THE DATABASE, CONTACT YOUR ADMINISTRATOR")
End If
```

Please help thank you

Comment: What do you expect when your already know the connection is wrong?

Comment: If you can't log into the database, you are **not** connected to the database. Perhaps you meant to ask something else? By the way, you usually connect to the database, perform your actions, then close the connection. You don't leave one monolithic connection at a time open.

Comment: I want to Know how to check if it is connected or not

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple, you could just put try and catch.

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Try
       conn.Open()
       If conn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
           MsgBox("open")
       Else
           MsgBox("no")
       End If
       conn.Close()
    Catch
       MsgBox("no")
    End Try
End Sub
```